# Google map with Jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, center

I am trying to display two google maps in one page. One is small map and then after the click on the view Large Map appears.
It displays the larger map in jquery dialog. The problem which i'm facing is that once i click on view Larger Map the jquery dialog is displayed but the google map is not center aligned. I tried to do it center-aligned but its not working

Below is my code:

```
var map,map2;
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var ipDialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 470,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Attractions",
        resizeStop: function (event, ui) { google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') },
        open: function (event, ui) { google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); },
    });

    $("#opener").on("click", function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });


});

    var gmarkers = [];

    var locations = <?php echo json_encode($location); ?>;

    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var icons = <?php echo stripslashes(json_encode($category_data)); ?>;   

    //Set Map
    var myOptions = {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.253205,-80.480347),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    {
        zoom: 9,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.253205,-80.480347),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    });
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"),
    {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.253205,-80.480347),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });  

    /*show('ClothingStore');
    show('Restaurant');*/
    <?php echo $cat; ?>

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      loc = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]);
      map.setCenter(loc);
      map2.setCenter(loc);
      createMarker(loc,"<div id='infoWindow'><strong>"+locations[i][0]+"</strong><br>"+locations[i][1]+"</div>",icons,locations[i][4]);

    }


    function createMarker(latlng,html,icons,category){

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: icons[category].icon,
        map: map
      }); 

     var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: icons[category].icon,
        map: map2
      }); 

      marker.mycategory = category; 
      gmarkers.push(marker);


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() { 
        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.open(map2, marker2);
      });

      /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() { 
        infowindow.close();
      });*/

      return marker;
    }

    // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
  function show(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }
    // == check the checkbox ==
    document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
  }


    // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
  function hide(category) {

    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
      }
    }
    // == clear the checkbox ==
    document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
    // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
   infowindow.close();
  }


// == a checkbox has been clicked ==
  function boxclick(box,category) {
    if (box.checked) {
      show(category);
    } else {
      hide(category);
    }
  }
```

Ok, But when i change autoOpen: true, in jquery dialog it show's markers are the center which I want. I don't no what's the problem in my code.

HTML is:

```
<div id="dialog">
                                <div style="float:left;width:180px;">
                                    <ul class="ulMap">

                                        <li>
                                             <?php echo clean($marker_category->cat_title); ?>: 
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo clean($marker_category->cat_title); ?>box" onclick="boxclick(this,'<?php echo clean($marker_category->cat_title); ?>')" />
                                        </li>
                                         <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    </ul>    
                                </div>
                                <div id="map" style="height:380px;width:680px;"></div>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                              </div>
<a href="javascrip:void(0);" id="opener">Large map</a>
```

What am i doing wrong here?